# QNAP - How to unmount/eject external drive as regular user?

Tags: qnap

I have a Qnap TS-453Be with QTS 4.3.6.
I've tried to find a way to unmount/eject an external drive/memory card as a regular user, but cant find it anywhere.
Nor can I find a way to give a regular user privileges for that.

Is it possible, then how?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: Cant find any reference at all, whether it should work or not in the documentation.